# An adjective that would substitute "underfunded" here?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

> Tom remains underfunded to start up a business.

The context is that this man has an excellent business plan and entrepreneurial spirit. But the bank wouldn't lend him money in absence of collateral.

In my view, the word "underfunded" properly stresses the fact that Tom lacks capital. However, according to Collins Dictionary, this word in most cases modify an organization or services. Are there any words that would fit in better?

To clarify, Tom LACKS enough funding. Still, he may turn to other institutions other than banks, a solution not very practical because the former ones charge exorbitantly high interest rate.

Comment: A quick google search tells me *unfunded* refers to not getting any funding and *underfunded* refers to inadequacy of funds. So is Tom unable to raise any money at all, or is he looking to raise additional money? Adding a clarification to your question will likely help you get better answers.

Comment: No online thesaurus has an entry for this word. Maybe _undercapitalized_ will work, but that seems to mean "A business that has insufficient capital to carry out its normal functions". Or _underfinanced_.

Comment: @BillFranke: Are you sure? According to the OED, it means *provide with insufficient funding.*

Comment: @Noah: No, I'm not sure, which is why I said "maybe". The best word is probably **broke** followed by **dirt poor**, but those aren't business-speak. Certainly, though, Tom is _underfinanced_ and _undercapitalized_ simply because **he doesn't have enough money to even begin his business or secure a loan**. Words may have denotations in the dictionary, but when they are used in the real world, they take on the meaning provided by the context in which they are used. Sometimes arguing about the meaning of a term is pointless: Just stipulate a meaning and that's what it means. Simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t think of any adjectives that would convey the same sense and meaning as *underfunding* in the context you’re using.

However *capital* would be a more appropriate word to use, given your context –

From OED –

> capital, adj. and n.2
>
> Real or financial assets possessing a monetary value; the stock with which a company, corporation, or individual enters into business; the total sum of shareholders' contributions in a joint-stock company;

And in phrase use –

> capital funding n.
>
> (a) capital raised by a business or company from lenders or shareholders;
>   (b) funding for capital or fixed assets.

Used in your context –

> Tom lacks capital funding to start up a business.

Comment: FWIW, Google Books has 7 instances of [he is underfunded](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he+is+underfunded%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and as many again with the component words split by a space or hypen. That's against a total of 67 for *he is undercapitalised/undercapitalized* (plus another 10 for the "split" versions). I think they're all perfectly valid in OP's context - but small as they are - those figures do tend to back you up in saying *capital* is more appropriate.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I think the word *capital* is the correct word for his *business* context. However, *undercapitalisation* does imply that the business already exists and lacks funding rather than insufficient funding to it *get started* in which case I think the phrase *lacks capital funding...* implies the correct meaning within that context.

Comment: I agree - I only did those GB searches to establish that *capitalised* is actually more likely than *funded* in the context of an individual. But there are so many variants applicable to OP's case (where the business doesn't even exist yet) that it would be impractical to search for them. Personally I'd probably say *"Tom is unable to secure start-up capital for his business [plan]"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I like the phrase *start-up capital* that implies precisely the right meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Any adjective meaning poor, prefixed by too is fine.

too poor

too hard-up

too cash-strapped